# Runnin hello word application on standard Android Emulator (rsxe5_android)

Tags: android, delphi, android-emulator, delphi-xe5

I am new to Delphi XE5 and I am attempting to Run a hello word application on standard Android Emulator (rsxe5_android).

I have the emulator running and the window CAPTION says 5554:rsxe5_android

1.) Is 5554 a port? If so, is it the correct one?

2.) how to speed things up. Are there tweaks I can do to make it run faster, especially on the second run when the emulator is already initialized and running

3.) after a very long time trying to run, I do not get anything displayed on the Android emulator and project closes out

shows a "Troubleshooting: Cannot Run on an Android Device or Emulator" troubleshooting help page

Comment: The android emulator is very slow, you need a GPU to run it properly. Running the emulator on my trusty Core2 duo laptop with integrated video show the same problem...

Comment: Running in the emulator is simply not feasible on Windows systems (it's a common problem). It's much easier to test/debug on an actual device through a USB connection. I test on both my Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7; the only issue I've ever had is occasionally having to restart the device (or the IDE, or both) if something goes really wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite is it as simple as just plugging in the device, or is there a set of directions somewhere for running it on the device directly?

Comment: @LIVESTUFF: read the documentation: [Running Your Android Application on an Android Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Running_Your_Android_Application_on_an_Android_Device).

Comment: What @Remy said. :) It's actually documented extremely well.

Comment: you can better not use an emulator it is so slow that it takes 1 minute to refresh a form.
That will be too long when you want to programm a full application. You better can use a real android device for test. Thats makes it a lot easier to test your code

Comment: We are all new to Delphi XE5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you haven't already, check the [Delphi XE5 release notes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Release_Notes_for_XE5#Notes_about_the_Delivered_Android_Emulator), regarding what they say about the emulator:

1) Don't run it in a VM

2) Make sure the Use GPU flag is on

Additionally, if both of those are done, check logcat to see if there are other issues reported (easiest to run the monitor app from within the Android SDK directory tree).

The best advice, though, is to get a real device. The emulator is emulating ARM instructions, which is necessary as Delphi generates ARM instructions for a native app. All that emulating is rather taxing on the performance...

Comment: Hi blong, thanks for responding. I am not runninhg it as part as AppWave and I am not running in a VM.  Where is the "Use GPU" flag located?  I have an IPhone 5. I really do need to pick up a Android device for devleopment testing

Comment: You can find it by following the links in the docwiki. Specifically check out: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator#Creating_an_Android_Emulator_Using_the_Android_Virtual_Device_Manager

Comment: Thanks. The reason I wasn't able to find it is because the default emulatordoes not allow you to edit that flag (as a matter of fact it is not even displayed). However, If I create a new emulator and duplicate all the values from the old one. It does display the flag and I was able to check it. And it worked!